# Is it possible to edit how advanced search web part is display?

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to edit how advanced search web part is display ?

I would like to remove language options in Advanced search web part SharePoint 2013.

Thank you,

Comment: Already found on settings of web part. Uncheck Show the languages picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please find the image which i have uploaded. it shows how to hide the languages picker after editing the search page and then edit the adv,search web part.
    [image: uncheck-lang-picker]